# What does it means that "a msi property can be passed to the server side when doing a managed installation?"

Tags: wix, windows-installer, server-side

What is a managed installation? What does it means that "a msi is running at server side"? And what does it means that "a msi property can be passed to server side"?

This question comes from the [wix documentation of "Property" element "Secure" attribute:](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/property.html)

```
Denotes that the Property can be passed to the server side when doing a managed installation with elevated privileges. See the SecureCustomProperties Property for more information.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Installer processes a UI sequence and then an Execute sequence.  The UI sequence runs client side (msiexec /I ..... )  and when you click the final proceed to install button it transitions to the server side (msiexec.exe running as the MSIServer service).  In Windows NT4.0-XP there was a pattern where an administer could "bless" an installer for a non-priv user to install. There are certain security sandboxes built into the installer to prevent a non privlidged user from using MSI to own a box in this scenario.  Starting with Windows Vista and UAC this managed installer pattern is used in most scenarios as the  client side starts as unprivileged and then becomes priviledged via a UAC prompt when transferring to the server side.

What the "SecureCustomProperties" property does is allow the MSI author to say that the following MSI properties are "trusted" and can be passed from the UI to the Execute (client -> server)  in this scenario.  Pretty much any properties associated with custom UI work in your MSI should be marked Public and Secure.  Also Upgrade table entries.

The below link is related to the question but doesn't directly address the question.  Still it's "required reading" to understand MSI and this topic.

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/)

Comment: I could definitely use more of "required reading" about MSI. I'm already learning about MSI almost everyday until 9 or 10pm, and there is so much more to learn to truly master it.

Comment: Totally understand. It goes easier with a mentor.  Learning it on my own back in 2003 involved reading the MSI SDK over and over and lots of trial and error / failure debugging.  It took 6 months for me to accept that MSI was better then imperative scripting and 12 months to have that "been there done that" comfort.